# progress bar with setMaxDuration

Tags: android, progress-bar, mediarecorder

I searched around but haven't found the answer. I'm recording video using `MediaRecorder` class and `setMaxDuration(10000)` method. However I want to show how much time has elapsed in a progress bar of this 10 seconds. I only see examples of using `getDuration` method with `MediaPlayer` class. Can anyone give me an example of how to use `MediaRecorder` with `progress bar`? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a [`Timer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html).

```
//fires once a second, decrease this to fire more frequently
private static final int TIMER_FREQ = 1000; 

//ProgressBar setup. You should do this in a way more tailored to your needs,
//but I've included it anyway
final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this); //where this is a Context
progressBar.setMax(10000);

Timer progressBarAdvancer = new Timer();
progressBarAdvancer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {
            progressBar.setProgress(progressBar.getProgress() + TIMER_FREQ);
        }
    },
    0, //Delay before first execution
    TIMER_FREQ);
```

This will operate the `progressBar` on a separate thread from the recording, but it will finish in 10 seconds, at which time you can stop the recording, finalize, and such.

Comment: Thank you very much! I did a little bit modification to set the progressbar to the element in the xml layout, and put the Timer part after mediaRecorder.start() function. And it works fine.